# Disable all UIResponderStandardEditActions when UITextfield is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uiresponder

I am currently trying to prevent all `UIResponderStandardEditActions` like `copy`, `paste`, `delete` from showing up when the `UITextfield` is empty. I would only like to show them if the user has types a message. I have tried 2 solutions and currently don't work, I'm not sure if its to do with `iOS 12` or. I have tried `overriding` the `canPerformAction` method both in a `UITextfield` `extension` and using a custom class later assigned to the `UITextfield` in the `Storyboard` but no luck. Is there another way to do this. Here is what I have tried.

```
extension UITextField {
    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            if self.text!.isEmpty {
                return false
            }

            return action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:))
        }
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override with your subclass and use this class instead of UITextField. By the way, this will disable copy paste,cut for whole conditions so that you need to add some `hasText: Bool` or related condition to the switch case.

```
@IBDesignable
class ActionsDisabledUITextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var isPasteEnabled: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var isSelectEnabled: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var isSelectAllEnabled: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var isCopyEnabled: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var isCutEnabled: Bool = false

    @IBInspectable var isDeleteEnabled: Bool = false

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        switch action {
        case #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) where !isPasteEnabled,
             #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) where !isSelectEnabled,
             #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)) where !isSelectAllEnabled,
             #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) where !isCopyEnabled,
             #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)) where !isCutEnabled,
             #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:)) where !isDeleteEnabled:
            return false
        default:
            //return true : this is not correct
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? I'm using this class in my more than one project.  How did you implement it? Can you please share some detail?